# Not able to drop GTT in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am not to drop a `gtt` in Oracle 12c. I dont know which `session` is keeping pending transaction. it is `on commit preserve rows` table.

```
drop  TABLE pjm.pjm_ecc_gtt1
Error report -
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
14452. 00000 -  "attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create, alter or drop an index on temporary
           table which is already in use.
*Action:   All the sessions using the session-specific temporary table have
           to truncate table and all the transactions using transaction
           specific temporary table have to end their transactions.
```

How can i abort session forcefully and drop it. I know `v$session` but how would I know which session using my table.

I truncated but still not able to drop.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_oracle_locked_objects.htm

Comment: thank you. No lock is there .

Comment: @Mahima We've faced the issue like this, but it was hang on `truncate` statement. The reason was the orphaned process, that was at the OS level, but not in sessions. Our DBA has managed to solve this, but I do not know how they identified that.

Comment: Which version or Oracle are you in, Any idea why you are dropping a Global temp table, because a Global, Unlike temporary tables from other database products such as MySQL and SQL Server, global temporary tables in Oracle are permanent database objects that store data on disk and visible to all sessions.
However, the data stored in the global temporary table is private to the session. In other words, each session can only access its own data in the global temporary table.

Comment: @hkandpal We have to alter the table actually. we need more columns on it. so we will drop and recreate. its new project, issue is in dev env only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query to get the session which has blocked it.

```
SELECT 'USER: '||s.username||' SID: '||s.sid||' SERIAL #: '||S.SERIAL# "USER HOLDING LOCK"
FROM v$lock l
,dba_objects o
,v$session s
WHERE l.id1 = o.object_id
AND s.sid = l.sid
AND o.owner = 'SSI' --user name
AND o.object_name = 'ABC_ECC_GTT1'; --table name
```

then run

```
alter system kill session 'sid, serial#';
```

Before killing the session ask the user who is holding , to politely close the session. killing session should be last option.